# What statistical model is used to calculate the test results for GWO?

Tags: computational-statistics, model

Google Website Optimizer (GWO) is a tool provided by Google to do [A/B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) and [MVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_testing) experiments on websites.

This has been an unanswered question for a long time so I thought I'd ask it here and see if I can get any help. Here is some documentation (clues) that Google has published about the statistics used:

- [All about statistics](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61146#stats)
- [Fractional versus Full Factorial analysis](http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=74818)

Example Data ([summary pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2511052/gwoTestResults/WebOptimizer-summary.pdf)):

- [XML](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2511052/gwoTestResults/WebsiteOptimizer.xml)
- [CSV](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2511052/gwoTestResults/WebsiteOptimizer.csv)

I (as well as many others) are interested in discovering the math used by Google, because no one has been able to reproduce their calculations yet.

Thank you in advance for any help that you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried asking Google itself?

Comment: [The question has been asked here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/websiteoptimizer/thread?tid=449ac5085f82912e&hl=en), where Google employees patrol, and there has been no answer. Also I asked someone that was able to talk to the engineers to ask this question for me, and he said that they would not say; so I wonder..

Comment: How did I not answer your question? Read the JMP book. It's free.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they simply use Choice Modeling. You would use conditional logistic regression to analyze it.

The people from JMP (SAS) have a nice (free) book about Design of Experiments and Choice Modeling.